# NFS mounting issues

Tags: nfs, nfsv4

Having a really weird problem with NFS mounts. When I mount my exports on my clients the directory and the files within are readable, but I can't write to the exported directory from the client neither can I enter hidden directories (~/.config) for example. When I list the files within the .config directory I get this:

```
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? nautilus
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? nemo
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? nitrogen
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? openbox
?????????? ? ? ? ?            ? OpenSCAD
```

/etc/export on server

```
/home/user 192.168.178.33(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1001,anongid=1001,nohide,crossmnt)
```

/etc/fstab on client

```
192.168.178.100:/home/user /home/user nfs rw,noauto,hard,user,exec 0 0
```

Comment: KIndly restart the nfs service  and Umount the directory in client and remount it

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /home/user/.config` on the server? The directory probably has the r bits but not the x bits.

Comment: I tried restarting and rebooting already. The umask on the server is completely fine. All permissions are set properly.

Comment: As I said I neither can create files nor can I enter hidden directories. Normal directories work fine.

Comment: If you're still working on this, have you tried backing off of the mount restrictions to figure out which one is causing the problem? I.e - just try with defaults and build from there? Also, I was messing with something earlier in the week and, like Mark mentioned, ran into a +x issue where the output was almost identical to what you're seeing.

Comment: I've seen this kind of output on a Kerberised NFS where the user listing the directory does not have a ticket. The solution is for the user to run `kinit`.